# Aerial picture - how can I extract water drainages on a crop (to vectorize them)

Tags: raster, imagery, digital-image-processing, aerial-photography, image-analysis

I have a RGB aerial picture of an agricultural crop. The drainages (hundreds of them) can be barely seen because they a very slightly greener then the surrounding crop area (picture is from April). How is it possible to make these drainages more visible in order to be able to vectorize them?

[image]

Comment: What software are you planning to use it ?

Comment: I use QGIS 2.14.2

Comment: if you get stuck with QGIS there are other free GIS that you can try http://astrogeology.usgs.gov/facilities/mrctr/gis-tools

Answer (score 1):

I would probably start by reclassifying your raster on the various bands and seeing how best you could isolate that specific green. I find the identify tool and checking out multiband scatterplots or histograms to be most helpful here. Once you get those depressions on one band and classify the rest as "NoData" running a Vectorize raster function should be the easy part.

Comment: Thank you! I think I have some keywords now that could lead the way. I already thought about using the identify tool but I didn't manage to reclassify the raster properly.